# spark.executor.cores Vs spark.executor.instance which one should I increase?

Tags: pyspark

In order to parallelize spark jobs, both the number of cores and the number of executor instances can be increased. What is the trade-off here and how should one pick the actual values of both the configs?

Answer (score 3):

- Advantages of increasing no. of cores over no. of executor are same
  as advantages of multi threaded over multi processes.
- No. of cores increase no. of threads for each executor and no. of
  executors will increase no. of Java process(i.e. Over all Spark
  executors on a cluster) .
- If you are looking to perform multiple operations in parallel on same
  Dataset/Dataframe then increase no .of cores per executor
- But if you are looking to perform process large amount of
  Dataset/Dataframe with relatively less parallelism then you can
  partition your day on key column and Spark will process your data on
  respective partition allocated executor.

I recommend that you read this [blog post](https://blog.cloudera.com/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/) from Cloudera.

*Bench marking you PySpark job by varying no. executors against no. of executor thread is the best way to come up with the right configuration for your application.*